# There is an entity table and a separate table with properties, how to build an elegant SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

There are tables in MySQL DB

```
entity
----------
ID NAME
1  entity1
2  entity2
3  entity3

entity_props
----------
ENTITY_ID PROP_ID PROP_VALUE
1          23      abc
1          24      def
1          25      xyz
```

When i need to select all entities which has property values 23="abc", 24="def" and 25="xyz" i use such request

```
SELECT ID 
FROM entity 
WHERE PROP_ID=23 AND PROP_VALUE="abc" AND ID IN 
    (SELECT ENTITY_ID FROM entity_props WHERE PROP_ID=24 AND PROP_VALUE="def" and ENTITY_ID IN
    (SELECT ENTITY_ID FROM entity_props WHERE PROP_ID=25 AND PROP_VALUE="xyz"))
```

But when there are too many properties it looks like terrible. Can you suggest how to simplyfiy it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway or lots of similar pages. The common recommendation is *don't use this approach*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . how about `group by` and `having`?

```
select entity_id
from entity_props ep
where (prop_id, prop_value) in ((23, 'abc'), (24, 'def'), (25, 'xyz'))
group by entity_id
having count(distinct prop_id) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of IN clause you could use INNER JOIN

```
SELECT ID 
FROM entity e
inner join (
  SELECT ENTITY_ID 
  FROM entity_props 
  WHERE PROP_ID=24 AND PROP_VALUE="def"
) t1 on e.ID = T1.ENTITY_ID
inner join (
  SELECT ENTITY_ID 
  FROM entity_props 
  WHERE PROP_ID=25 AND PROP_VALUE="xyz"
) t2 on e.ID = T2.ENTITY_ID
```